# How to specify delimiter when using libreoffice --convert-to on command line?

Tags: libreoffice

I have a an excel file that I need to convert to csv on a linux machine. Initially I used the command "libreoffice --convert-to csv file_name" but the issue is that some of the fields of the excel file had commas in them, so when comma is used to delimit the csv file, all the fields are thrown off. Is there a way I can specify what I want the delimiter to be? (I would prefer to use a pipe)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]" to learn how this site works. -- If fields can contain the separator, I would expect that such fields are quoted. How do you read the CSV? Is it possible, that your reading part does not pay attention to the quoting? Please add new information by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I actually think it's clear what the OP was asking, and I have the same problem: `libreffoice --convert-to csv <file>` converts to a `csv` using `,` as delimiter. When exporting via the UI, there is the option to set a different csv delimiter (e.g. a pipe `|`, as OP suggests, more common `;` maybe).
The question is whether it is possible to specify this also on the CLI, i.e. get the equivalent behaviour of the UI dialogue with a custom delimiter from a shell without going through the UI.